# Customizing the Email text sent to users on granting permssions to various sites?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, email, email-templates

Where and what exactly should I be looking at editing to change the subject. body and other text of the default email that is sent by sharepoint notifying the user that he or she has been granted permission to a site/list/document etc.....

Thanks

Comment: Could you please tell me which version you're working with? I might suggest you a work around without having to modify files in 14/12 hive

Comment: Falak  Im working on sharepoint 2010 Enterprise

Comment: Awesome, I have an good workaround to the problem ;). I will post it soon

Comment: hey Falak! Any luck on the workaround. I'd appreciate it if you could post it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry dude, I didn't have time to do it. But I will post it soon :)

Comment: So, solution is now posted :). Enjoy SharePointing and extending it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on the same topic.
Is not possible to change the email body for e.g. "Welcome to the group email":

"Welcome to the 'BLABLA' SharePoint group. BLABLA has added you to the 'BLABLA' group for this SharePoint site. 
As a member of this SharePoint group, you can: 
* Participate in the SharePoint site at: .................
* View the group home page at:......................................

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
What is a SharePoint site?

A SharePoint site is a Web site that provides a central storage and collaboration space for documents, information, and ideas. A SharePoint site is a tool for collaboration, just like a telephone is a tool for communication, or a meeting is a tool for decision making. A SharePoint site helps groups of people (whether work teams or social groups) share information and work together. For example, a SharePoint site can help you:

- Coordinate projects, calendars, and schedules.
- Discuss ideas and review documents or proposals.
- Share information and keep in touch with other people."

The bottom of the email can be changed can be changed from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources\core.en-US.rex`

The start of the email can be changed from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\wss.en-US.rex`

The rest I couldn't find it in neither database or resources.

Please post if you have a solution (even custom code)

Comment: see my response. I have posted the solution.

Comment: For future reference, if you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for further help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This technically is possible, however you would be editing the resource files installed by SharePoint.  Doing this is NOT supported by Microsoft, could break things, and could get overwritten during future updates.

If you are feeling adventurous in a test environment, however, the location of the resource files is here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources.

The resource files are XML, so you can edit them in a text editor.

Again, **I strongly advise against this**, however if you want to play around with it in a test environment, that is where you would looke.

Comment: John Thats what I thought too. Thanks for that insight. I'm surprised Microsoft dint provide a means to simply edit the entire mail based a business's brand and need. Thanks again though.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is the solution which customizes the Email text (Subject and the Message) sent to users on granting permssions to various sites. Normally, it is not possible without modifying SharePoint OOTB files. But my solution works without having to modify any OOTB box SharePoint files.

**How it works:**

In SharePoint 2010, Permissions are granted using the Aclinv.aspx. Aclinv.aspx is the out of the box dialog for granting permissions. So, together with jQuery and Javascript I have developed a Feature which changes the OOTB text that is sent to the users, while granting permissions.

I have published the source code to CodePlex: http://customemailtemplate.codeplex.com/

**Note**: At the moment, I have only developed this solution as proof of concept  to show we can change Custom email template. A further extension could be to dynamically fetch Email Subject and Email Body's text from the property bags, using jQuery.

Hope it will help many awesome SharePointers out there ;)

Comment: Thank you for posting the code.
But this doesn't replace the text that is added by Sharepoint (e.g. "As a member of this SharePoint group, you can: * Participate in the SharePoint site at: ................. * View the group home page at:......................................" ) , but only the text of the users, and that is not wanted. BR,
Corina